# Apps Script listitem - make bullets instead of numbered?

Tags: google-apps-script, listitem

I am able to use the appendListItem in apps script to add a bunch of items to a google doc as a numbered list.  Is there any method for changing this from numbered to bulleted?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You should be able to use [ListItem.setGlyphType](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/class_documentapp_listitem#setGlyphType) to choose a bulleted list.

Comment: That worked great.  Looks like this:
      var doc.appendListItem(whatever).setGlyphType(DocumentApp.GlyphType.BULLET);