# How to append a list item at a specific position in Google Docs

Tags: google-apps-script

I have a Google Doc that I want to populate from google spreadsheet with some text at a specific placemarker {text}

It should look like:

**Header 1**

- Item one
- Item two

**Header 2**

- Item next

I managed to add "Header 1" with

`getBody.findtext("{text}").getParent.asParagaph().appendText`

But adding a bullet list is something I struggle with.

Comment: I have solved it using the outlined solution in: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11211434/insert-image-into-a-specified-location

Answer (score 2):

This should work

```
doc.appendListItem(whatever).setGlyphType(DocumentApp.GlyphType.BULLET)
```

Answer came from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11438526/apps-script-listitem-make-bullets-instead-of-numbered)

Comment: Thanx. The bullet list I managed. What still is not disable by me it's to append the list in a specific position in the document. Paragraph with text {placeholder} paragraph with text. The paragraph with text are already in the document.